# Create a View under Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build

I am trying to create a view to contain multiple jobs under Jenkins Dashboard

Steps I had followed

Jenkins dashboard >EditView>(_Empty)>Replaced the name and saved

however I don't see the new View get reflected.

Answer (score 3):

**Steps to create  new view in Jenkins for Jobs :**

1. Login to Jenkins
2. Click Jenkins and go to homepage ( only if not in homepage where all jobs are there)
3. Click on **New View** in Left vertical List
4. Select **List View**
5. Give **view name**
6. **Select** the jobs you want in view
7. Click **Ok** and **Apply**

Answer (score 2):

If you're editing a view, it must already exist. Then it probably wouldn't be empty.

To create a new view, click on the '+' tab at the end of your current set of view tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that below properties are set appropriately,without defining portlets the jobs wouldn't get displayed on the view created.

[image: Jenkins Edit view page]

Answer (score 0):

I think your view is not completed and Jenkins doesn't show a list of created views to manage.

Try to http://yourJenkinsIP:port/view/name of created view/configure

Delete or edit this view.

Note that if your view name has any white space you should use it and fill it with it's exact name.